# getting perplexed about this code, not seeing any thing wrong, but not printing out what i'm expecting

Tags: javascript

hello pls i need someone to tell me what i'm doing wrong on this line of code

```
 else if((x%3===0) && (x%5===0))
    {
        console.log("JuliaJames");
```

it is displaying "julia " instead of "JuliaJames"

```
var x=1;

while(x<=20)
{
    if (x%3===0)
    {
        console.log("Julia");
    }
    else if(x%5===0)
    {
        console.log("James");
    }
    else if((x%3===0) && (x%5===0))
    {
        console.log("JuliaJames");
    }
    else if(!(x%3===0 && x%5===0))
    {
        console.log(x);
    }

    x=x+1;
}
```

Comment: why is PHP  tagged?

Comment: Works better if you state WHAT do you expect it to do. This way we only see what it does.

Comment: @delboy1978uk, that is because php and javascript are juxtaposed with the if statement

Comment: ok cool, check my answer, i sent you a link to jsbin showing a working version

Comment: how is this a php question? there's also no html here.

Comment: *"that is because php and javascript are juxtaposed with the if statement"* - you have php and js in together, huh?

Comment: @fred i never said it was a php question , what am trying to posit is that as a php developer their is much possibilities that you can also answer the question with the if statement.thanks

Comment: you shouldn't use the php tag, nor the html tag if there's no relevance or code; it's misleading and makes the question unclear.

Comment: *"their is much possibilities that you can also answer the question with the if statement"* - why should I submit an answer? You've been given many and one should be marked as solved by accepting one and closing the question.

Comment: Playing ball isn't a one hand/one team thing. You should learn how Stack works and then give back to the community. You also didn't update the question. For that reason, I gave the question a minus vote.

Comment: @fred thanks, i think i have graps something new from you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order is wrong. 5 and 3 will both work for 15, so put the if with most conditions at the top like this:

```
var x=1;

while(x<=20)
{
    if ((x%3===0) && (x%5===0))
    {
        console.log("JuliaJames");
    }
    else if(x%5===0)
    {
        console.log("James");
    }
    else if(x%3===0)
    {
        console.log("Julia");
    }
    else if(!(x%3===0 && x%5===0))
    {
        console.log(x);
    }

    x=x+1;
}
```

Check it out here: http://jsbin.com/faheforoko/edit?js,console,output

Comment: no problem, can you mark as correct answer please? glad i could help! have a great day! :-)

Answer (score 0):

That `else if` is gonna be executed only if the previous ones are not, so if `x` is indeed divisible by 3, it's gonna execute the first `if` and it's not gonna keep evaluating any other conditions.

One solution would be putting the more restrictive `if` statements on the top (i.e starting with 3 && 5)

Comment: @dandave no problem! You should mark an answer as "correct" by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Once a condition is `true`, the others are skiped in an `else if` structure.

You need to take an other approach by checking first the most complexed condition and then the onece with less complexity.

The last check is not necessary, because it is the part where you need to display the result, because no other check is `true`.

```js
var x = 1;
while (x <= 20) {
    if ((x % 3 === 0) && (x % 5 === 0)) {
        console.log("JuliaJames");
    } else if (x % 3 === 0) {
        console.log("Julia");
    } else if (x % 5 === 0) {
        console.log("James");
    } else {
        console.log(x);
    }
    ++x;
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing through your algorithm manually and verify that your steps are the same ones the program is doing. The reason you are getting the wrong output is because of the order that you have setup your rules.

Comment: thanks i quote " because of the order that you have setup your rules.", have rearranged, really appreciate